# Rhino Mocks step-by-step tutorials

Tags: tdd, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

I realise that there exist some posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185021/rhino-mocks-good-tutorials) which have asked the same question. However, the links on the suggested page do not work (it simply takes me back to the blog homepage).

I'm looking for a tutorial which does not have any assumed prior [Rhino Mocks](http://dotnetpattern.com/Rhino-Mocks-Tutorial) knowledge.

I need a step-by-step guide which explains the basics (stubs vs. mocks vs. expect.call), how the `Record()`, `ReplayAll()`, `VerifyAll()`, when/why you use `Repeat.Any()` etc., work.

I have a rough understanding after reading some of the documentation (which I found some articles to be useful, but most to be confusing at best), but I need some more examples with detailed explanations on how to use Rhino Mocks.

Comment: There's this a bit not updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185021/rhino-mocks-good-tutorials

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666606

Answer (score 27):

I think the best links, which are both up to date, and starting from the basics are:

1. [Getting Started with Rhino Mocks (AAA)](http://adamprescott.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/getting-started-with-rhino-mocks-aaa/)
2. [Using Rhino.Mocks - quick guide to generating mocks and stubs](http://www.wrightfully.com/using-rhino-mocks-quick-guide-to-generating-mocks-and-stubs/)